# performing routing with drill chuck

Tags: technique

I have a Shopmate radial arm saw with a router outlet spindle.
I can not find a collet chuck attachment to perform routing. 
Is it possible and save to attach a normal drill chuck to perform routing work at 20000 rpm?

Comment: No, a normal drill chuck won't withstand those sorts of rotational speeds. It's not just that it probably won't be able to hold on to the bit securely, there is a real risk *the chuck itself* might disintegrate.

Comment: Looks like an answer @Graphus

Comment: Look for a chuck from a high-speed air drill.  They typically spin a lot faster than electric drills.  Really, though, the answer for this question is "the manufacturer rates it to that speed".

Comment: check this out for a source on [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/WARDS-POWR-KRAFT-ROUTING-AND-SHAPER-KITS-/121162196378?rmvSB=true) If you are lucky, it looks like you can score collets for both spindles for about $30. (part numbers agree with the Shopmate brand

Answer (score 2):

No. A drill chuck is designed for perhaps 2000rpm, 1/10th of your spindle speed. It’s also designed only to take a compressive axis force, not longitudinal forces, or the (if you get something wrong wrong) axial forces pulling the chuck from the spindle. 
Anything going wrong at 20,000rpm is extremely high energy, so it’s not worth the risks. 
ER16/20 etc collets are available cheap on eBay and are intended for routers.